# Unable to Send Email from SMTP Server

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

Hello I'm using PHPMailer to send email . I have implemented following code to send email.

```
<?php

// require('PHPMail/class.phpmailer.php');
require('PHPMail/PHPMailerAutoload.php');  
$mail = new PHPMailer();  
$mail->IsSMTP();  
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;  
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; 
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port = 587;      
$mail->Username = "myname@gmail.com";   
$mail->Password = "test";
$mail->SetFrom('myname@gmail.com','Test'); 
$mail->Subject = "A Test Email From Gmail";  
$mail->Body = "Body From Gmail"; 
$mail->AddAddress('sender@gmail.com', 'Name'); 
if($mail->Send())
{

    echo "Message sent!";

}

else
{

        echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;

}

?>
```

I received email while sending from localhost.

When I try to send email from server it displays following error

**SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting**

Do I have to enable email setting on my server ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If this code works locally but not remotely, then it is a good indicator of your problem being server configurations. Looking at the troubleshoot doc it says you can "If you set SMTPDebug = 2 or higher, you will see what the remote SMTP server says." How you go about getting that "says", is not clear - I would presume it would be output in the $mail->ErrorInfo variable. If you can provide the contents of that output someone may be able to help you further and quicker.

Comment: A good quick thing to check if you have access to the server terminal is this: dig +short smtp.gmail.com, to confirm your DNS is working correctly server side.

Comment: also check if you have port 587 open to outgoing connections, test with this `telnet smtp.gmail.com 587` if you get a `timeout` this is probably it.

Comment: There are over 800 nearly identical questions on SO about this exact message - please search before posting. If you'd tried following the link in the error message, you would know exactly how to fix this error.

Answer (score 3):

It means that PHPMailer is unable to contact the SMTP server you have specified in the Host property.

Login to your Gmail account and visit : https://www.google.com/accounts/DisplayUnlockCaptcha

and

https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

and turn on "Access for less secure apps"

to Give your app and access to your account.

Comment: Previously I was unable to send from localhost as well. I turned on setting for access for less secure apps and only I was able to send from localhost. But it does not works in server

Comment: Go back and turn it on, It seem google always turns it off automatically immediately you send the first message.

Comment: I will recommend that you use you own server mailer for better accessibility, I will recommend that you use you own server mailer for better accessibility You can do that by changing your host to mail.yourdomain.com